# умножение многочленов на основе связного списка - C++

Tags: c++, список, переопределение

Написал код по созданию многочленов, не могу понять как реализовать их умножение.

```
class mnogochlen;
class element
{
private:
    int stepen;
    int koof;
    int freem;
    element *Next;

public:
    friend mnogochlen;
    mnogochlen friend operator *(mnogochlen &P, mnogochlen &Q); /* умножение многочленов*/
};
class mnogochlen {
    element *Head;
    element *Elem;
    element *Current;
public:
    friend element;
    void sozdanie()/*создание многочлена */
    {
        cout << "Введите степень многочлена: ";
        int power;
        cin >> power;
        Head = NULL;
        int p;
        p = power;
        for (int i = 0; i <= p; i++)
        {
            if (Head == NULL)
            {
                Elem = new element;
                cout << "Введите коэф. степени "<<power<<": ";
                cin >> Elem->koof;
                Elem->stepen = power;
                Elem->Next = NULL;
                Elem->freem = NULL;
                Head = Elem;
                Current = Elem;
            }
            else
            {
                if (power == 0)
                {
                    Elem = new element;
                    cout << "Введите свободный член: " ;
                    Elem->stepen = NULL;
                    Elem->koof = NULL;
                    Elem->Next = NULL;
                    cin >> Elem->freem;
                    Current->Next = Elem;
                    Current = Elem;
                }
                else
                {
                    Elem = new element;
                    cout << "Введите коэф. степени " << power << ": ";
                    cin >> Elem->koof;
                    Elem->stepen = power;
                    Elem->Next = NULL;
                    Elem->freem = NULL;
                    Current->Next = Elem;
                    Current = Elem;
                }
            }
            power = power - 1;
        }
    }
mnogochlen friend operator *(mnogochlen &P, mnogochlen &Q); /* умножение многочленов*/

};
```

Вот тут нужно как-то реализовать умножение

```
mnogochlen operator *(mnogochlen &P, mnogochlen &Q)

{
    mnogochlen d;
    d.Elem = NULL;
    element *p1 = P.Head;
    element *q1 = Q.Head;


}
```

Comment: класс имеет 3 указателья на другой класс, одновременно являясь его другом, тот в свою очередь друг этого класса ,  таким  образом может управлять  представлением того, кто  управляет  его представлением... Я бы не пытался реализовывать такое

Answer (score 1):

Просто разберитесь с математикой,а потом в код подставить не составит труда:)

http://www.pm298.ru/mnog.php

Умножение многочленов :
         [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В частности,[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @PauloBerezini Да,спасибо.Исправил